# Expressing Lipschitz function similar to the mean value theorem.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lipschitz-functions

Let $f(x):\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ be a globally Lipschitz function. Does this mean that there exists a matrix $M(x,y)$ such that:

$$f(x)-f(y)=M(x,y)[x-y]$$

I do not want to use the Jacobian matrix because the function is not differentiable. If this is true, can I write $M(x,y)$ as follows

$$M(x,y)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
\big[f(x)-f(y)\big]\frac{(x-y)^T}{\|x-y\|^2} & x\neq y\\
0 & x=y
\end{array}\right.$$

Comment: Yes, I think what you write makes sense. The global Lipschitzian nature is required to ensure that the entries are bounded.

Comment: It is globally Lipschitz **iff** there is some constant $M$ such that $\|f(x)-f(y)\| \le M \|x-y\|$ for all $x,y$.

Comment: I don't understand fully your question: for $x$ and $y$ fixed, you are asking whether there is a matrix sending some vector of $\mathbb{R}^n$ to another vector of $\mathbb{R}^n$. There's plenty of those. Maybe you want some kind of regularity for $M(x,y)$?